# Абстрактная фабрика и клиент-серверное приложение

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, java, клиент-сервер

Здравствуйте уважаемые, изучаю паттерн проектирования абстрактная фабрика. Задался целью реализовать собственное простенькое клиент серверное приложение на протоколе UDP использующее данный паттерн, но немного не укладывается в голове как эти вещи можно уместить. Не могли бы вы немного направить в нужное русло и дать какие то советы по реализации именно этого паттерна в реализации данной проблемы?

P.S.
В гугл не слать, там уже все перерыто

P.P.S.
Язык Java

Comment: Вы каким-то конкретным образом хотите сочетать использование абстрактной фабрики и клиент-серверности? А то не совсем понятно чем вопросы отдельного использования этих двух подходов отличаются от вопросов использования их в сочетании друг с другом.

Comment: Натягивать паттерн на задачу - хуже нет. Паттерн должен помогать вам решать задачу, или упрощать жизнь, или предоставлять готовое решение проблемы. В данном примере "клиент-серверное приложение" необходимо как раз натянуть паттерн. Может быть придумаете пример, где этот паттерн поможет вам?

Comment: @Deadkenny ну может человек хочет, к примеру, абстрагироваться от взаимодействия с конкретной базой данных, заимев абстрактную фабрику DataAccessObject'ов. А потом менять их хоть на заглушки, хоть на другие базы.

Comment: Ну можно так натянуть :) В любом случае лениво писать. Может кто-нибудь и напишет в ответе. А так можно посмотреть реализацию на википедии например.

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)